# Dynamic Columns sum

Tags: sql, dynamic, rows

```
EmpID_D | CompanyID_D | 80C    | Other Loss | Total1
1839    | 734         | 150000 | 100000     | 171600
```

Above given is my table `ITdeclr`.
Its' a dynamic table 
I want the sum of `80c` and `Other Loss` as `Total1`.
`80C` and `OtherLoss` is dynamically creating. Like wise n no of column may come.
How to handle this ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Have you tried `[80c] + [Other Loss]`?

Comment: Actually this columns are dynamic . So i cannot use [80c] + [Other Loss]

Comment: @MeghaPrakasan Can you give us more detail from your question?
How did you create those columns ?

Comment: i got another solution its working fine now. i made two different global table and did changes accordingly since it has some fixed column. EXEC('update  b set b.Total1= b.Total1 +  case when a.Total1>='+@MaxLimit +'then  '+@MaxLimit+'  else a.Total1 end 
    FROM ##ITDeclarationDetails80c a
    inner join ##ITDeclarationDetails  b on a.EmpID_D=b.EmpID_D')